# Expected arrival date changed - Australian Visitor 600 Visa

Tags: visas, australia

I filed an application for a Visitor 600 visa. Part of the application asked when I was expecting to arrive, and I said 8 November. We have however changed our plans to be earlier by one day (arriving 7 November).

A friend says this arrival date is not important, because the visa will be valid from grant date.

Is this true? Is it necessary to inform them of this change or not?

Comment: What does your friend mean by ‘grant date’? Some visas are ‘granted’ with validity starting on the date of travel stated in the application.

Comment: For her I think it was the date that the application was approved. But I was also not certain that she was right. Basically, for Australia there seems to be one way to apply for this visa. So I was wondering if people know how it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Grant date" refers to the date the decision is made to approve the visa.

[Section 68 of the *Migration Act 1958*](https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/C2018C00337/Html/Volume_1#_Toc522030533) sets out when a visa is in effect (i.e. starts):

> (1)  Subject to subsection (2), a visa has effect as soon as it is granted.
>
> (2)  A visa may provide that it comes into effect at the beginning of a day, being a day after its grant:
>
> (a)  specified in the visa; or
>
> (b)  when an event, specified in the visa, happens.
>
> ...

So unless some other date is specified in the visa grant notice, the person can enter Australia immediately.

Comment: For completeness - I just received the visa grant. It has no mention of when I said I plan to enter the country. Just the grant date as we concluded.  So, no need to worry.